# Having internet access with no data plan

Tags: mobile-data, internet

I have a pay as you go plan with no data. I have always been able to visit and search on Google and my carrier's website by turning on the data plan on phone (even though I have no data and there appears to be a cross on LTE sign meaning there are no connections).

Over the past year one day I noticed that by turning on data (no WIFI) I have full internet access (seemingly uncapped). But this connection did come and go when I put my phone in the flight mode. So after the flights I had to restart phone multiple times or quickly turn the flight mode on and off (usually multiple times) until I could get access to the internet.

Now recently after a flight this has stopped working, by restarting phone or turning the flight mode on and off quickly I can still make the cross on the LTE sign go away and the phone thinks that it has internet access but it can only go to Google.com. The connection also seems leaky meaning I sometimes get notification from apps that do not function without WIFI. This has made me wonder that what is the best way to diagnose this situation that why I do get leaky internet access on data with a plan with a no data plan?

- The situation is replicable on a different phone too.

Comment: Most likely your carrier has detected the bug and fixed it so you now have to pay for a data plan like everybody else.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your insight. The first part of your statement might be true but the second part of it is definitely incorrect! The weird thing is that this has happened many times on and off and usually has something to do with either flight mode or sudden location change which seems to be such random things.